ROS2 Clock locking to Node state
Is there a way pause clock advancement in ROS2 until all nodes have completed their processing?

I don't think the clock is commonly used for stepping/syncing nodes like that. but if you wanted to, you can switch to "sim time" and nodes will advance their clock based on what's published to the /clock topic (which you can then control), instead of the typical system time. Every node has use_sim_time parameter for this purpose.
Sim time is usually used with either a simulator or rosbag playback: when the simulator/rosbag is paused, the clock will stop, and nodes using a Rate/timer won't advance
Hope that helps!

Do you know how the clock stepping operation works? IE can a node communicate to another node while the clock is held fixed? If not do you have ideas on an approach which will result in simulated playback independent of system specs?
